linux + how to close connection that are not in used
from netstat -anp | grep :8088 | grep EST
we can see the following connection ( is example from our hadoop server )
tcp        0      0 192.83.23.112:42360     192.83.66.114:8088      ESTABLISHED 49627/python
tcp        0      0 192.83.23.112:59984     192.83.23.112:8088      ESTABLISHED 52985/python3
tcp        0      0 192.83.23.112:60328     192.83.23.112:8088      ESTABLISHED 55009/python
tcp        0      0 192.83.23.112:60118     192.83.23.112:8088      ESTABLISHED 13306/python3
tcp        0      0 192.90.23.112:59976     192.90.23.112:8088      ESTABLISHED 52921/python3

the connection are ESTABLISHED but if we take some of PID and verify if PID is running then we can see that some of them are not running
example
 ps -ef | grep      49627
root      58975 121146  0 18:45 pts/18   00:00:00 grep --color=auto 49627


ps -ef | grep     52985
root      57435 121146  0 18:45 pts/18   00:00:00 grep --color=auto 52985

so is it possible to close the connections as
tcp        0      0 192.83.23.112:42360     192.83.66.114:8088      ESTABLISHED 49627/python
tcp        0      0 192.83.23.112:59984     192.83.23.112:8088      ESTABLISHED 52985/python3

so on the next time we not see them from netstat -anp | grep :8088 | grep EST

Rather than writing ps -ef | grep      49627, write ps 49627.  If it is gone, retry the netstat.  Worst case, you might have a wildly forking program, or worse, a rootkit.  You might also try lsof
